# Grails ${appName} Parameter substitution

Tags: grails

My problem is simple - the ${appName} property substitution in Config.groovy does not appear to be working for me.

I have a config item called `path.to.resources = ${appName}/videos`, but when I read that from my controller using `grailsApplication.config.path.to.resources`, I get `${appName}/videos` instead of `myAppName/videos`.

I'm using Grails 2.0.4 and STS

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
path.to.resources = "${appName}/videos"
```

Comment: Double-quoting it seemed to work - I had single-quote. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, yes. [String interpolation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Strings+and+GString#StringsandGString-GStrings) in Groovy only works with double quotes. Single quotes is used for String literals.